# Comprehensive hand do compendium and paraphernalia app

Tags: android, charts, android-app

I am looking for a compete hand and finger drawing represention and animation app (would be nice if the app ran on smartphones, such as Android).

The app should ideally

- show how to make animations of animals and characters by setting (and moving), hands, in front of a projector or light source, onto a wall.
- show  how to paint hands to make them into animated heads.
- show how to draw hands with fingers configured into various hand and finger shapes to make them into animated characters.
- show how there exist various hand types and shapes

Thanks.